# How to store full web page (HTML + CSS) with CefSharp?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I want to store the visited web pages in memory, to replay them again in the same order but the **css** is not taken into account on some web sites and the web pages replayed are so ugly compared to the originals.

I'm using this code to store *Web Pages*:

```
private void WebBrowserFrameLoadEnded(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        // This will open notePad++
        // WebBrowser.ViewSource();

        if ( false == m_bModeReplay )
        {
           
            WebBrowser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
            {
                // List<string> m_listContent
                m_listContent.Add(taskHtml.Result);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And replay them like this (each 5s I load the next page):

```
void timer_Tick_PlayFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (m_iIndexPlayBackList < m_listContent.Count)
    {
        string strContent = m_listContent[m_iIndexPlayBackList];
        WebBrowser.LoadHtml(strContent, "http://www.google.fr");

        m_iIndexPlayBackList++;
    }
}
```

How to deal with CSS constraints please to have a complete display of the page ?

I'm using:
*CefSharp.Common.116.0.150*
*ChromiumWebBrowser*

Comment: You could use a response filter to save the responses then a resource handler to intercept subsequent requests. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#response-filtering and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#resourcehandler